# $SU(2)_R$ symmetry and mass term for hypermultiplet

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, group-theory, supersymmetry

I study [N=2 supersymmetric dynamics for pedestrians by
Yuji Tachikawa](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2684), and I don't understand how $SU(2)_R$ symmetry demands that $[\mu, \mu^\dagger] = 0$.

[image]

I will be very appreciate for answers.